# NYTProf execution time when profiling and when no profiling

Tags: perl, debugging, profiling, devel-nytprof

Just, wanted to make sure.

I have small python script that measures program execution time, it simply saves time before external program starts and then substracts this value from time after program ends execution.

When running this script on perl script it shows execution time of 0.49263 and when running same script with NYTProf and looking inside HTML report generated by nytprofhtml I can see that execution time is 0.80784, almost twice more.

Is this OK? I suppose profiling should increase execution time but that much?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal because Devel::NYTProf needs to look at every single statement (and blocks, and so on). It needs to write profiling data to disk for each statement. The cost for this is quite high. That's why you should not run it in production.

There's some info on how to make it run faster in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf#MAKING-NYTPROF-FASTER).

---

If you run on a linux command line, there is no need for any other programs to get the execution time of a command. Simply do this on the shell:

```
$ time perl foo.pl
```

Comment: OK. Of course it has it's own cost. But NYTProf knows how much time it took for it's own job (write data on disk, measure times, bla bla) and knows how much time was taken by target/profiled program. So this way it can separate self used time and time actually used by program.